# Rhino Mocks stub only returns null

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have been beating my head over this for a day. Nothing on the internet about this. I have a stubbed function. When it is called within rhino mocks it only returns null but I want it to return a different value. Take a look:

```
[Test]
public void GetViewingInfo_Throw_WhenViewingIDReturnsNull()
{
     _managementDataController
          .Stub(s => s.GetManagementByID(1))
          .Return(new Info(){ApprovedByEmployeeID = 123});

     Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
          _managementBusinessController.GetViewingInfo(1));
}
```

Now basically `.Return(new Info(){ApprovedByEmployeeID = 123});` always returns null. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the `GetViewingInfo` code:

```
var manage = _managementDataController.GetManagementByID(managementID);
InvalidValueGuard.ThrowInvalidOperationExceptionOn(() => manage == null, "");
```

I put a breakpoint at InvalidValueGuard and the manage variable always returns null.

Comment: So is `GetManagementByID` called by `GetViewingInfo`? Can you show that code?

Comment: Is `GetManagementByID` actually being called with an argument of `1`? The default value will be returned if the call does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating a concrete class.

```
Info info = new Info();

_managementDataController
          .Stub(s => s.GetManagementByID(1))
          .Return(info);
```

I have no idea why this works. I am guessing closure does not work when you send a class in return method.